# Can we change the tint of an image in Corona?

Tags: coronasdk

How to change the tint of an image in Corona SDK like we change the tint of a sprite in cocos2D Using CCTintTo.
Is there anything like CCTintTo in Corona.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the `CCTintTo` API, but if you're a Corona subscriber, you can download the latest daily build and use the `setFillColor` method on an image to set the tint to any RGB color.  Ansca just released a new public build of Corona, but I haven't downloaded it to see if image tinting made the cut.

Here's the blog post that introduced the tinting feature:

http://blog.anscamobile.com/2011/09/tints-and-gradients/

**UPDATE:**

This *is* in the latest public build (704), but there seems to be a bug re: tinting images.  Once tinted with `setFillColor`, the tint won't change with a subsequent call.  The workaround is to "jiggle" the image right after the `setFillColor` call, e.g.:

```
image:setFillColor( 255,0,0 )
-- image will be tinted red
image:setFillColor( 0,255,0 )
-- image will still be red
image:translate(-1,0)
image:translate(1,0)
-- now image will be tinted green
```

See this page for a discussion of this issue:

http://developer.anscamobile.com/forum/2011/12/06/question-about-setfillcolor-images

Comment: I would add that there are some limitations. For instance setFillColor will not work on an image which is using a mask.